# Creating Zip without third party DLLs. Getting Part URI must start with a forward slash error

Tags: c#, archive

I have a problem and due to that reason i am working on a pure c# solution to zip files. This is for a classic asp site and I will register my dll on ther server. I already have tested other third party libraries...

I am getting the following error:
Part URI must start with a forward slash.

Here is the implementation that i have been able to build by googling around. My error is in method "AddFileToZip" on line:

```
PackagePart newFilePackagePart = zipFilePackage.CreatePart(partURI, contentType, CompressionOption.Normal);

[TestMethod]
public void ArchiveFile()
{
    string dir = "\\\\filebox01\\data\\test";
    string file = "text.xls";

    ZipClassic zip = new ZipClassic();

    bool ok = zip.ArchiveFile(dir, file, "singleFileArchive.zip");
    Assert.IsTrue(ok);
}
```

**Main method:**

```
public bool ArchiveFile(string fileDir, string fileToArchive, string newArchiveFileName)
{
    FileSystem fso = new FileSystem();

    bool ok = !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileDir) &&
              !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileToArchive) &&
              fso.FileExists(Path.Combine(fileDir, fileToArchive)) &&
              fileToArchive.Contains(".");


    if (ok)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newArchiveFileName))
        {
            if (!newArchiveFileName.ToLower().Contains(".zip"))
                newArchiveFileName = String.Concat(newArchiveFileName, ".zip");
        }
        else
        {
            string filePart = fileToArchive.Substring(0, fileToArchive.LastIndexOf(".", System.StringComparison.Ordinal));
            newArchiveFileName = String.Concat(filePart, ".zip");
        }

        //if archve file already exists then delete it
        if (fso.FileExists(Path.Combine(fileDir, newArchiveFileName)))
            ok = fso.FileDelete(Path.Combine(fileDir, newArchiveFileName));
    }

    if (ok)
    {
        Impersonate impersonate = new Impersonate();
        impersonate.DoImpersonate();

        Package zipFile = Package.Open(Path.Combine(fileDir, newArchiveFileName), FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(fileDir, fileToArchive));
        AddFileToZip(file, zipFile);
        zipFile.Close();

        impersonate.Dispose();

        ok = fso.FileExists(Path.Combine(fileDir, newArchiveFileName));
    }
    return ok;
}

protected void AddFileToZip(FileInfo file, Package zipFilePackage)
{
    string physicalfilePath = file.FullName;

    //Check for file existing. If file does not exists,
    //then add in the report to generate at the end of the process.
    if (File.Exists(physicalfilePath))
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(physicalfilePath);

        // Remove the section of the path that has "root defined"
        physicalfilePath = physicalfilePath.Replace("./", "");

        // remove space from the file name and replace it with "_"
        physicalfilePath = physicalfilePath.Replace(fileName, fileName.Replace(" ", "_"));

        try
        {
            //Define URI for this file that needs to be added within the Zip file.
            Uri partURI = new Uri(physicalfilePath, UriKind.Relative);
            string contentType = GetFileContentType(physicalfilePath);
            PackagePart newFilePackagePart = zipFilePackage.CreatePart(partURI, contentType, CompressionOption.Normal);
            byte[] fileContent = File.ReadAllBytes(physicalfilePath);
            newFilePackagePart.GetStream().Write(fileContent, 0, fileContent.Length);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Unable to archive: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

protected string GetFileContentType(string path)
{
    string contentType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Zip;
    switch (Path.GetExtension(path).ToLower())
    {
        case (".xml"):
        {
            contentType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Xml;
            break;
        }

        case (".txt"):
        {
            contentType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain;
            break;
        }

        case (".rtf"):
        {
            contentType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Rtf;
            break;
        }

        case (".gif"):
        {
            contentType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Gif;
            break;
        }

        case (".jpeg"):
        {
            contentType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg;
            break;
        }

        case (".tiff"):
        {
            contentType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Tiff;
            break;
        }

        case (".pdf"):
        {
            contentType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf;
            break;
        }

        case (".doc"):
        case (".docx"):
        case (".ppt"):
        case (".xls"):
        {
            contentType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.RichText;
            break;
        }
    }

    return contentType;
}
```

Comment: What did `new Uri(physicalfilePath, UriKind.Relative)` give back?  Tip: A verbatim string literal using @ is easier to read: `string dir = @"\\filebox01\data\test";`.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#". That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Made this change: string dir = @"\\filebox01\data\test\text.xls"; Uri partURI = new Uri(physicalfilePath, UriKind.Relative); gives {\\filebox01\data\test\text.xls} When i expand partURI, for OriginalString i get the above value and IsAbsoluteUri=false. All remaining items throw the following exception: System.InvalidOperationException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was in creating partUri. I have used the full path where as it should have been the file name.

```
Uri partUri = PackUriHelper.CreatePartUri(new Uri(String.Concat(@".\", fileName), UriKind.Relative));
```

This link helped to reolve the problem.

http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2007/10/25/creating-zip-archives-in-net-without-an-external-library-like-sharpziplib.aspx